# Debug printed barcode (code 128)

Tags: barcode, encode, barcode-scanner, code128

We have a software which generate a document with barcodes (code 128) included. It's an old close software so for us is a blackbox and we can't modify the output (document template, font, etc.). Usually the generated barcode work without problems, but sometimes is not possible read it. With this problematic codes we tried several barcode scanners and mobile apps without success.

The encoded string has the format:

> productID/personID/category

and sometimes changing a single character broke the code. Just right now I have 2 codes just with different categories, and one of them is not working:

- OK: (*149339/20/G_MA_Loet*) [image]
- WRONG: (*149339/110/R_MA_DIV*) [image]

I tried visually compare both codes and I believe the 'start char.' and 'stop char.' look the same. I guess the checksum value can be wrong(?)

I'm trying to debug the problem and I was looking for a way get a 'raw' output from the bars in binary and compare it with the Code128 encode values 128, but I didn't find any tool for it.

I don't have previous experience with barcodes. Now I'm stuck and I don't have idea how debug the problem: it's a software bug? a font bug? Do you have some idea what more to try?

Comment: Dou you only encode numerical digits?  Code 128 has alphanumeric variantes (A/B) and a numeric only variant, Codee 128C to encode numbers with high density.  Which one do you use, do you know that?

Comment: Obviously alphanumeric, says my scanner ;)

Comment: Can you please post the input characters of both codes, the OK one _and_ the WRONG one?

Comment: @MarcBalmer thank you for be in contact. Q was updated with the input characters of both codes.

Comment: Try to use another libraries. I see you marked start of difference by blue dot?

Comment: yes, there is a blue dot. How to use another libraries? I can't change nothing in the software (the company which developed it don't exist more, and it's close), and I don't know if/how read the code with other library? Just right now I have in my hand a Honeywell Xenon 1900 scanner and all apps from Google Play for try :)

Comment: Your software is doing it wrong.  Check with an online generator, e.g. http://barcode.tec-it.com/de and compare the result for 149339/110/R_MA_DIV.  It looks different.

Comment: Yes, I encoded the string in others apps (even I created a small C# app) and I get a readable code. Concretely the problematic software is Microsoft XAL (former Concorde XAL) and I don't have idea how continue with this issue.